# what is the command to put my computer in standby mode?

Tags: keyboard, sleep, standby

I have a Microsoft keyboard that I just bought, but it has no sleep button. what it does have is 5 programmable keys that can open programs. I want to program one of the buttons to put the computer in standby mode (where the power light is flashing). what I am using right now is "Rundll32.exe Powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState Sleep" and "rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0" but these do something different (the power light is off, not flashing) what would be a command that I would use to put the computer in standby mode?

Comment: Ah, was hoping to be able to give an answer from the `shutdown` command-line program, but it looks like it only does hibernate, but not standby.

Comment: Shutdown -h can also hibernate the computer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Shutdown**

```
%windir%\System32\shutdown.exe -s
```

**Reboot**

```
%windir%\System32\shutdown.exe -r
```

**Logoff**

```
%windir%\System32\shutdown.exe -l
```

**Standby**

```
%windir%\System32\rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState Standby
```

**Hibernate**

```
%windir%\System32\rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState Hibernate
```

Comment: There's no `Turn On` command? :-)

Comment: [Do not use `rundll32`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/15/58973.aspx) for functions that are not specifically designed as such.

Comment: interesting @grawity observation!

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can find a PowerShell command to do that, save it on a script file and set your keyboard execute that.

Check on google for "Powershell Standby", [this](http://www.stockenterprises.ca/post/Put-your-PC-into-Standby-or-Hibernate-with-Powershell.aspx) looks good.

Answer (score 0):

You can also customise what the power button (the button you turn on your computer with) does. You can set it to cause hibernate, sleep or shutdown. This can be changed via power options.